# Is API Gateway needed when using Microfrontends?

Tags: api-gateway, micro-frontend

When doing microservices it's quite a common and good practice to have a top layer called API-Gateway, that sits in front of a group of microservices, to facilitate requests and delivery of data and services.

When using MicroFrontends to compose an UI app from multiple sub-apps (MFE), I cannot really see a benefit about still using an API gateway to communicate between each MFE and its corresponding Microservice.

In many schemas, an API-Gateway is still used in front of the microservices

Example here :

[image]

But the fact that each microfrontend is its own app also probably means it will communicate with its own API. In this case I would either use a thin API layer over each microservice, and then make each MFE communicate directly with this layer, because a MFE probably won't ever need to read data from another MFE (this would go against the spirit of MFE, or am I wrong ?).

What kind of approach would you use in your projects ?